# How can I count non-empty cells based on a value elsewhere in the row?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a table like this:

```
+---+---------+----------+--------+
|   |    A    |    B     |   C    |
+---+---------+----------+--------+
| 1 | John    | Judy     | Team A |
| 2 | Brandon | Bethany  | Team B |
| 3 | Agnes   |          | Team A |
| 4 | William | Welma    | Team B |
| 5 | Tom     | Theresa  | Team B |
| 6 | Peter   |          | Team A |
+---+---------+----------+--------+
```

Counting the total number of people is easy:

```
=COUNTA(A1:B6) -> 10
```

How can I count the number of people on each of the teams? i.e., Team A is 4, Team B is 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine `COUNTA()` with [`FILTER()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197) to achieve this result:

```
=COUNTA(FILTER(A:B, C:C="Team A")) -> 4
=COUNTA(FILTER(A:B, C:C="Team B")) -> 6
```